# SonarQube compare versions of the same project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube6.3

i'd like to compare code coverage and other metrics between two different versions of my project, but using the leaking period mechanism i was not able to get the view i want.

I would like to compare version metrics [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdzbE.jpg):

On my researches i've read something similar was possible on older versions of sonar.

Can someone give a tip on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of SonarQube, you don't have built-in tables that show you a list of metrics over different versions of your project.

Still, you can see the evolution of each metric over the past versions when you go to "Measures > [select the metric] > History". You will see something like:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the history view has been removed, I can't see it :(

Comment: Ah, my bad - it's different UI element now :) There's a little stock ticker UI button to show history for a measurement element - not every metric supports this though. The 'activity' screen also covers off the overview I was looking for.